# Django is there a benefit of checking every view with `method=='POST':`

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views, api-design

Is there a benefit to starting every one of my view functions with `if request.method=='POST':` or `if request.method=='GET':`? Or would I just be adding unnecessary lines of code?

I've followed a few examples where views for Ajax are all checking if the HTTP is made with GET.

Could it, for example, prevent DDOS from latching on to a POST method and hammering it with GETs? Or, more practically, prevent API consumers from incorrectly PATCHing when they should PUT or POST?

```
def employee_delete(request, uid):
    if request.method == 'DELETE':

def employee_detail(request, uid):
    if request.method == 'GET':

def employee_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

def employee_update(request, uid):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
```

Comment: You can use the `@require_http_method(..)` decorator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods

Comment: But the reason why this might be a good idea is because `GET` is not supposed to have side-effects, and if an "internet spider" (a bot) or user accidently visits an `employee_delete` link through GET, the employee is deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a benefit to starting every one of my view functions with if `request.method=='POST':`

**Yes**, even if you only support one method, it is better to guard this. The HTTP protocol specifies that GET requests, should not have side-effects (well effects in the sense of counting visitors are probably no problem, but not something that changes the "entities" of your business logic is strictly speaking not acceptable).

Now "web crawlers" (for example used by search engines or scrapers) typically detect links on a page, and make GET requests on these links (since they aim to "discover" new pages). If there is a view behind this URL that, for example, deletes an employee, it can happen that *accidentally* a "web crawler" will edit your database.

Other methods like `GET`, `HEAD`, `PUT` and `DELETE` should be *idempotent* (that means that making the same request twice, should have the same side-effects, as making the request only once).

So by not "protecting" your views, you lose a layer of "protection" against accidental misuse of your webserver.

A hacker could also aim to make a request with another method, and see how the server responds in a search to find exploits: for example, look if a server makes certain assumptions on the method that fail when performing a DELETE request. For example, a rather generic view implementation that handles all methods, could - if not guarded - unintentionally allow the deletion of files (for example you write a generic view to create and edit content can be "misused" by a hacker by using a `DELETE` request that the parent view implemented, but should not be supported for that specific entity).

In the early days, some HTTP webservers for example did not check authentication when a HEAD request was used. As a result, a hacker could, by trying several HEAD requests "scan" the id space, and thus obtain knowledge what id's were filled in in the database. Of course that in itself does not leak *much* data, but it is a vulnerability that can be *used* as a first step in hacking data.

Note that although Django has *some* protection against this when using, for example, class-based views, a person can just use *any* string for the request. So a person can write as method `FOOBAR`. If the view for example specifies `if request.method == 'POST'`, and an `else:` statement, it can thus be used, to enter the `else` statement with a non-GET method.

But regardless of the use-case, "better be safe than sorry", and guarding the HTTP methods, is just one of the aspects to check.

That being said, if only a subset of methods are allowed, you can use the [**`@require_http_methods`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods) decorator:

> ```
> from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
>
> @require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
> def my_view(request):
>     # I can assume now that only GET or POST requests make it this far
>     # ...
>     pass
> ```

This decorator thus makes it more elegant to guard that the proper method is used.

Answer (score 2):

To offer a different perspective, I think your question illustrates why you should consider using class-based views, which make life so much simpler when dealing with such problems.

For example the generic [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) already comes with all the logic built in to restrict the type of HTTP request. It will let you perform a GET request to initialise a form, but require a POST request to process data. Thus you can't accidentally trigger data to be saved through a GET request.

It also provides the framework for proper form data validation, error handling etc - which you would have to implement yourself in a procedural view.

Same goes for the range of other views that Django provides - `UpdateView`, `DetailView` etc.

All Django class-based views come with a [`http_method_names`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.http_method_names) attribute that you can use to control which methods are allowed on your views, e.g.,

```
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):

    # only GET and POST allowed. Anything else will get a 405 Method Not Allowed response.
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Logic for GET requests goes here.

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Logic for POST requests goes here. No risk of it getting mixed up with GET.
```

This in addition to providing a lot of other helpers for things like form handling, template loading etc. Procedural views may *feel* simpler initially, but you will quickly realise that you end up having to write a lot more code to get them to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you! So it looks like the form fields can be specified right in the CreateView. Does the field cleaning and error message happen in the view too?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: Yes, you can specify which fields the `CreateView` exposes by setting the `fields` attribute on the view. And yes, it will handle cleaning and validation of the fields based on your model definition.